# Firebase cloud functions: can't extract parameters when invoking a callable function

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the Flutter SDK to call a cloud function. I add a parameter `someField` but on the cloud side, it cannot be retrieved and is always `undefined`. This is how I call the cloud function

```
static Future<void> doSomething() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
    functionName: 'myFunction',
  );
  dynamic resp = await callable.call(
    <String, dynamic>{
      'someField': 'Hurray!',
    },
  );
}
```

The cloud function is written as follows

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
      const myParameter = req.body.someField; // is always Undefined
      // also tried
      // req.query.someField
      // req.params.someField
      doSomething(myParamter)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) on the client app with [HTTPS functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) on the backend.  Please review the documentation to understand the difference between them.  If you want to use the Firebase SDK on the client to invoke a Cloud Functions, you should declare that using `onCall` instead of `onRequest`.  When you write a callable function with `onCall`, you will have access to the input arguments via the first parameter delivered to the callback.

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // data.someField should be populated from your client request
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there was only http functions but it seems there are two types. Just started off with cloud functions today.